# API logic to get latest weather information

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm writing weather API which fetches METAR and TAFS data from aviation weather stations.

Data changes once an hour.

Need to fetch latest weather information, but in my code I cannot make it to fetch it after an hour.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const ADDS = require('adds');
var moment = require('moment');

// adds moment to the locals
router.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.locals.moment = moment;
  next();
});

const avWet = Promise.all([
  ADDS('metars', {
      stationString: 'KCRX,KMSL,KSNH,KTUP',
      hoursBeforeNow: 1,
      mostRecentForEachStation: true
    }),
    ADDS('tafs', {
      stationString: 'KTUP,KMSL',
      hoursBeforeNow: 1,
       mostRecentForEachStation: true
    })
  ])
  .then(results => {
       
  const parsedData = results;
    
      /* GET home page. */
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
       
    res.render('wet_av', {
      parsedData
       
    })
   })
  });
  
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: how You start the app? can You give more info in Your question?

Comment: Sure - I use "Express application generator" .
So my start script: 
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
I take out nodemon on production.

Comment: how You start does not mean how You generated it

Comment: I use a package.json with the start script.
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  },
I take out nodemon on the production

Comment: replace start script with: `nodemon —watch ./ ./bin/www`

Comment: Thanks, num8er.
I did it, but the weather API doesn't update until on the hour.
What about in production?

Comment: You’re strange, code it to work as You want. Use the database. I helped with auto restarting the app if it changes.

Comment: Write different question

Comment: The API just updated and my APP still won't refresh. I did a force refresh.

Comment: what You mean “refresh”? Write in Your question use case with expectation.

Comment: num8er - I think your script change may have worked. 
I had to go to one of my ejs files and save first, then nodemon reloaded and I refreshed the browser and the  api made a new call. Worked.
I use this script:
```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "watch": "nodemon ./bin/www --watch ./ --ext '*' localhost 3000"
}
```
 in my package.json file.
I still can't get it to refresh in the browser with a new api call  in production.

Comment: My problem again:
I open my ExpressJS weather app web page and I get the current weather. I then want to refresh my page later and get the new current weather updated, but I just get the same weather I got the first time. This is on my hosting server not local development.

>How do I get the weather app to update the api call for the new weather? Is it my code or is this a problem with all api updates? Do I need PM2? Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to restart Your app to get data, so You don't have to use nodemon or another watcher which will restart the app too.

1. Simply write Your method which will get data and store it in variable
2. Schedule it to check for new data
3. Call that method to get data and push to render

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ADDS = require('adds');
const moment = require('moment');

// adds moment to the locals
router.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.locals.moment = moment;
    next();
});


let weatherInformation = null;
let weatherInformationParsedAt = 0;

async function getWeatherInformation() { // [1] method that will get data from api
    const startOfHour = moment().startOf('hour').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:')+'00';
    const currentTimeString = moment().startOf('minute').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');

    // if there is no data then need to parse
    let needToParse = !weatherInformation;

    // forcing to parse if it's 00'th minute of hour
    if (startOfHour === currentTimeString &&
        Date.now() - weatherInformationParsedAt > 30000
    ) { // if start of hour
        needToParse = true;
    }

    // forcing to parse if data is old more than 2 mins, making sure we have fresh data
    if (!needToParse &&
        weatherInformation &&
        Date.now() - weatherInformationParsedAt > 120000
    ) {
        needToParse = true;
    }

    try {
        // if need to parse so let's fetch again (that's for caching)
        if (needToParse) {
            const query = {
                hoursBeforeNow: 1,
                mostRecentForEachStation: true,
            };

            const results = await Promise.all([
                ADDS('metars', {
                    ...query,
                    stationString: 'KCRX,KMSL,KSNH,KTUP',
                }),

                ADDS('tafs', {
                    ...query,
                    stationString: 'KTUP,KMSL',
                }),
            ]);

            weatherInformation = results;
            weatherInformationParsedAt = Date.now();
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    return weatherInformation;
}
setInterval(getWeatherInformation, 1000); // [2] every second call method which checks for changes


router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    const parsedData = await getWeatherInformation(); // [3] calling method to get weather information

    res.render('wet_av', {
        parsedData,
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You got me really thinking num8er. It's been my code all along. This has been driving me crazy and thinking about giving nodejs up.
Your code looks great, I'm getting errors.
First error: just your code.
`
    C:\Users\walla\OneDrive\Aptana MISC\2016\Aptana Projects\avwet\wetav\routes\wet_av.js:28
      const results = await Promise.all([
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
`

Comment: Second error: after placing async before your function
```
C:\Users\walla\OneDrive\Aptana MISC\2016\Aptana Projects\avwet\wetav\routes\wet_av.js:50
setInterval(getWeatherInformation, WEATHER_INFO_RELOAD_TIMEOUT); // [2] once a minute will call method

```

Comment: NOTE: this is aviation weather. It updates once every hour. I only need it to update when the client refreshes their browser. Thanks num8er

Comment: @W.Young it does not make sense, in an hour METAR also may change, does not matter it's aviation data or not. So that's why scheduler runs once a minute.

Comment: @W.Young I've fixed code. But here is the thing - You're a developer why not simply fix exceptions? is it hard to see typos?

Comment: @W.Young I've updated the code, IMHO it's best solution to have fresh data

Comment: It's working.....don't know if it updates yet. I'm not a full developer yet, just learning nodejs. The big picture hasn't fully come together, but getting clearer. I'm slow at it right now.
I just get stuck, sorry. I learn by you explaining why you make these changes, which I'm still don't fully understand yet.....
Your forced update: I understand it, that the code updates every hour if there's an update and it holds the new update in a variable until the client refreshes their browser, then the client gets the new weather update.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your great code fix works. My web page updates when I refresh my browser with the updated weather.  I'm hosting it on A2hosting, I also have a VPS at Hostgator and will try it soon.

>Question: would it work without the constant weather checks?
Why the interval weather checks? Can the code not go fetch the updated weather when the client refreshes their browser?